# How to position a dialog box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a problem with the positioning of my dialog box it apperas always in the upper left corner it should be centered in the middle but how to do that?

Here is my script code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#confirmdelete").on("click", function(e) {
        var link = this;

        e.preventDefault();

        $("<div>Soll das Kundenkonto gelöscht werden?</div>").dialog({
            buttons: {
                "Ja, bitte löschen": function() {
                    window.location = link.href;
                },
                "Nein": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: should be centered by default if you included proper css and have valid page html including doctype

Comment: CSS is responsible for element positioning, not JS.

Comment: Is this your actual code or is this just an example? [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o9kywqLf/) shows that the box should already be centered unless you explicitly position it.

Comment: As already pointed out, default position is `{ my: "center", at: "center", of: window }`. See the documentation for the [position](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position) option

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<div class="dialog">Soll das Kundenkonto gelöscht werden?</div>').

.dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -150px;
  width: 300px;
}
```